# T-SQL Query to SELECT rows with same values of several columns (Azure SQL Database)

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure

I need help with writing a T-SQL query on a table shown on the picture below. The table has ambiguous info about buildings, some of them appears more then one time, that is wrong. I need to select only rows that has the same street and building values, for I can manually delete bad rows then. So I want to select rows 1,2,4,5 on the picture below. I use an Azure SQL Database, it has some limitations on T-SQL.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Azure supports subqueries and window functions.  So, try this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by street, building) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```